# What is the diference between a normal boot and resume option after a recovery boot?

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, recovery-mode

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.5 server machine that hangs on boot, but if I choose recovery mode and then resume, everything's ok.

Any clue?!

Comment: I had this case on two Ubuntu installations some time . I couldn't find find why. Hopefully someone can point to it is plus in recovery mode.

Comment: I'm currently stuck in a situation like this, but nomodeset is already set on my main kernel. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566528/flashed-bios-of-aorus-gaming-7-x399-and-can-only-boot-ubuntu-18-04-recovery-mode (which maybe I should have posted on AskUbuntu instead... is there an acceptable way to cross post?)

Answer (score 6):

Recovery mode grub menu entry has the following differences from normal startup:

1. It has `nomodeset` boot option set
2. It emits `recovery` event instead of startup which does the following:

   - starts services: hostname, console-setup, setvtrb
   - emits mounted event for /run to trigger resolvconf and mounted-run.

With resume from the recovery console the start event is emmited and the normal boot is started.

**sources:**

- `/etc/grub/grub.cfg`
- `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init`
- `/etc/init/friendly-recovery.conf`

My guess is that you should boot your machine with the `nomodeset` option

Comment: It seems right, I though it's related to graphics. Thank you for listing those sources which make really quick overview of recovery boot.  I know `grub.cfg` generated boot menu & `friendly-recovery.conf` which launch recovery panel, but `initramfs-tools/init` is it already included in `initrd`? If yes, is it the first which runs after mounting ramdisk?

Comment: @Sneetsher initramfs-tools/init is the init process spawned by the kernel. Among others things, it is responsible to mount the root filesystem and spawn /sbin/init. It is part of initramfs-tools that generate the initramfs - being called by the kernel installation hooks.

Answer (score -2):

Resume just makes any programs you previously had open or in use that are opened and controlled within the User Interface or opened by the user will be restarted and restored to when last used. Normal boot just gives you a fresh new UI.

Comment: Resume after recovery boot (on grub)

Comment: NOTHING BAD WILL HAPPEN!