# Boot stuck at IRQ 22

Tags: boot, grub2, ram

I'm running Ubuntu 14 on a Macbook any my system froze so I performed a hard reboot. However when it came back up, it shows me the grub menu but no matter which kernel I pick the boot freezes with the line:

```
irq 22, io mem 0xd3489200
```

What does this mean? Is this indicating a hardware fault?

Google finds me several similar posts but no solutions.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/508089/what-is-the-diference-between-a-normal-boot-and-resume-option-after-a-recovery-b . Could you try booting with `nomodeset` boot option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the original issue was, but when I rebooted using a "recovery kernel", that seemed to get around the issue, and now my machine boots normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try two things:

## 1 easy solution

Just unplug (from electricity) your computer for 10 seconds,
plug again and it might work! (yes it does)

## 2 if it doesn't work (edit grub)

The solution was in Grub
go to: Advanced Options
There I went to the 'Recovery mode option'
prees 'e' to go to the editor.
edit the line

```
linux /vmlinuz-3.0.2..... nomodeset acpi=off
```

press F10 to boot.
That way it did boot, but it didn't recognize the keyboard.

This confirmed with an 'acpi' issue.

The next thing I did is a restarted the computer
and went testing the different acpi options
in [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI#Debugging_procedure).

The one that did it for me was

```
nolapic
```

F10 once again and then my keyboard responded
from there I ran 'fsck'.
and start again.