# Ubuntu loading screen stuck, how to recover from this situation?

Tags: 15.10

I have done nothing. Just normally uses my 15.10 Willy. But after the last shutdown at 1 pm I couldn't get pass the loading screen. There is very important things in my laptop. Anyway to recover this position? 
Please help me
I mean it

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell anything without knowing the output. 
You can try choosing older kernel (maybe kernel update caused this), by selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu" in Grub menu at the beginning (if Grub menu doesn't appear, hold Shift while booting).

Much better will be access kernel boot options by pressing "e" and remove "splash" and the "quiet" entries from the boot parameters to make Ubuntu display the output during boot and read what the error is.
To get logs of this, you need to access your hard drive from LiveCD or LiveUSB and take logs from /var/log, e.g.:

```
/var/log/boot.log
/var/log/dmesg
```

Using LiveUSB, You can also rescue your data to another computer.

There is a lot of questions on Ubuntu boot, so knowing the output, you can google for your error.

Comment: I have opened recovery menu and use resume option. Logged in the black terminal. After a few minutes my normal logging screen appears again logged in. I've thought everything is fine but when I try to restart, it goes into the same situation.

Comment: @SayantanKoley  This problem can be googled. Here are two links where it seems to be [video driver problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2120067) and [suggested "nomodeset" boot option for kernel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/508089/what-is-the-diference-between-a-normal-boot-and-resume-option-after-a-recovery-b).  Here is [another link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do) about this option.